# Why not super().__init__(Model,self) in Pytorch

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, pytorch

For torch.nn.Module()

According to the official documentation: 
Base class for all neural network modules.
Your models should also subclass this class.
Modules can also contain other Modules, allowing to nest them in a tree structure. You can assign the submodules as regular attributes.

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        return F.relu(self.conv2(x))
```

It used `super(Model, self).__init__()` 
Why not `super().__init__(Model, self)`

Comment: Because the second one would call an init function that takes 2 parameters?

Comment: For ```super(Model, self).__init__()``` is it actually the same as ```super().__init__()```

Comment: Your question however lists `super().__init__(Model, self)`, which is different. And `super()` only works since Python 3, so presumably the docs want to be backwards compatible to Python 2

Comment: make sense, thanks !

Answer (score 12):

This construct:

```
super().__init__(self)
```

is valid only in Python 3.x whereas the following construct,

```
super(Model, self).__init__()
```

works both in Python 2.x and Python 3.x. So, the PyTorch developers didn't want to break all the code that's written in Python 2.x by enforcing the [Python 3.x syntax of `super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) since both constructs essentially do the same thing in this case, which is initializing the following variables:

```
    self.training = True
    self._parameters = OrderedDict()
    self._buffers = OrderedDict()
    self._backward_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._forward_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._forward_pre_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._state_dict_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._load_state_dict_pre_hooks = OrderedDict()
    self._modules = OrderedDict()
```

For details, see the relevant discussion in the PyTorch forum on the topic, [is-there-a-reason-why-people-use-super-class-self-init-instead-of-super-init?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-a-reason-why-people-use-super-class-self-init-instead-of-super-init/15891)

Answer (score 3):

There is another approach that is usable in both Python 2.x and 3.x.  It doesn't use the complex `super()` function, its meaning is clear and is not potentially misleading if there are two superclasses involved.  You can just call the superclass's constructor directly:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
```